# Do I need anything other than VS2010 beta 2 to use "Code Only" in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, code-first

Is it possible to use "code only" with Entity Framework in an out-of-the box VS2010 Beta 2, or do I need some additional download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work in Beta 2, but [you can get enhancements to code-only in CTP 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/04/ado-net-entity-framework-community-technology-preview-released.aspx), which is an add-on to Beta 2.